# Angular App does not build on Heroku

Tags: heroku, angular-cli

I have an angular 2 app which builds fine on my MAC. Here are the relevant versions:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.30
node: 7.6.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.30
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
```

Today I created a heroku app and I have been trying to deploy the app on it using heroku CLI. I have followed the steps [here](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352) to do so.

Although it compiles properly on my MAC, on heroku it gives many errors, the most common of which are something like:

```
ERROR in /tmp/build_56020fc9198e03c2d2338a818aaf8e5d/src/$$_gendir/app/admin/configuration/email-templates/email-template-form/email-template-form.component.ngfactory.ts (589,18): Property 'loadingOverlay' is private and only accessible within class 'BaseComponent'.
```

Here are the package versions in my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.30",
    "@angular/common": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.9",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.62",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "2.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.30",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.9",
      "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
      "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
      "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
      "typescript": "2.0.10"
  }
```

There are more, but I have included only the ones that are relevant.

Comment: try upgrading your version of angular-cli. Have solved problems like this before by upgrading. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. I deleted my `node_modules` and ran `npm install` again. It updated all my packages and I got the same errors as `Heroku`. I then fixed all of them and deployed it. It worked. But if you see my `package.json`, the versions I have given for angular packages are exact (not ^ or ˜) so I did not understand why `Heroku` was building it with a different version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a solution to this. Heroku caches all the NPM packages (it does the same for Bower.

If you deploy the app after changing the versions in the `package.json`, heroku does not download the new versions, instead uses the cached ones.

To force Heroku to download the packages instead of using the cached ones, do this:

```
$ heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
$ git commit -am 'disable node_modules cache' --allow-empty
$ git push heroku master
```

You can unset if after a successfull push, otherwise, after every push it will download all the packages listed in package.json.

```
$heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
```